# Pattern matching with Strings seperated by dots in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to find strings that match a particular pattern.
For example in the following condition:

```
if("1.6.1.1.60885.5".matches("1.6.1.1.n.5".replaceAll("n", "\\\\d{0,10}")))
```

then it should be true, since n can be any integer. 60885 is an integer. This works fine.

```
if("1.6.1.1.60885".matches("1.6.1.1.n.5".replaceAll("n", "\\\\d{0,10}")))
```

then it should be false. But I get this also as true.

I just need the n to be any integer but the dots position has to be considered. Can anyone suggest how can I achieve this.

Comment: replaceAll("n", "\\d{0,10}) ??

Comment: If I use replaceAll("n", "\\d{0,10}"), then  if("1.6.1.1.60885.5".matches("1.6.1.1.n.5".replaceAll("n", "\\d{0,10}"))) will give false instead of giving true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
matches("1\\.6\\.1\\.1\\.n\\.5",... )
```

The '.' is a wildcard and must be quoted.

(wildcard = "match any character")